# VBScript find path folder then input path into text txt file

Tags: vbscript

I have been trying to find and write a vbscript that enables me to find a filepath and then insert it's location into a text.txt file

**For example:**

click on Find.vbs

window opens to search for folder or drive

select c:\test folder

are you sure you want to select c:\test folder? prompt

click yes button

**in the text.txt file**

the word driveselect changes to c:\test

I found this that opens the window and then lets me select a file, it then opens a msgbox to show the file name, but will not select a folder only

```
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec=wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE>
<script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
sFileSelected = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
wscript.echo sFileSelected
```

there are a few codes that i found to change the text in a word file, but not text file with input.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Excel Application's FileDialog to select a folder.

```
Dim FolderName, msg, msgResponse

Do
    FolderName = getSelectedFolderPath
    msg = "Are you sure you want to select " & vbCrLf & FolderName & "?"
    msgResponse =  MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo,"") 
Loop Until Len(FolderName) = 0 Or msgResponse = vbYes

Function getSelectedFolderPath
    Const msoFileDialogFolderPicker = 4
    Dim xlApp
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With xlApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            getSelectedFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    xlApp.Quit
End Function
```